# Excel like autocomplete when list is in quick edit mode

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there an out of the box way to get a column in SharePoint online to give autocomplete suggestions based on what's previously been entered, on other rows in the same column - like in Excel?

I've got a column for entering the company name of a customer. I don't want to make it a lookup field to a list of companies, but I want it to give me autocomplete capabilities based on the previous company names that have been entered.

Comment: Have you looked in to using a managed metadata column with an open termset?

Comment: The what and the whatnow? You just gave me something to Google. Thanks! ;)

Comment: Sorry! But Managed metadata is a quite awesome concept in SP: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/introduction-to-managed-metadata-HA102832521.aspx it is built up with terms, termsets, and termgroups. You can bind a site column to a termset. If the termset is "open", the users can add terms ti this termsets while filling in your field. If similar terms already exists, they will be shown as suggestions while the user is typing!

Comment: No, I was unclear, I was actually thankful for you giving me a hint on where to begin. But thanks even more for the clarification.